# Can not access Magento admin. Error message. Help needed

Tags: admin

For some reason I am no longer able to access my Magento admin. The website is live and works perfectly on the frontend, but I can not access the backend and I get the below error message

There has been an error processing your request

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 1341617007993

My host provider is having difficulty fixing this and I have restored both files and database to an earlier version when I know it was working. The issue developed yesterday and we have restored back to the 5th May and still no joy.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Details of the error log 1341617007993

```
a:5:{i:0;s:59:"Mage registry key "_singleton/mgt_base/feed" already exists";i:1;s:1351:"#0 /home/giggleberries/public_html/app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/giggleberries/public_html/app/Mage.php(477): Mage::register('_singleton/mgt_...', false)
#2 /home/giggleberries/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage::getSingleton('mgt_base/feed')
#3 /home/giggleberries/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('adminhtml_contr...', Array)
#4 /home/giggleberries/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(159): Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_contr...', Array)
#5 /home/giggleberries/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(407): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /home/giggleberries/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
```

Comment: Could you post the content of the `var/report/1341617007993` please

Comment: Login to your FTP and move to \var\report\ directory and find the file with name as 1341617007993. open this file in any editor and debug the error this file will show you what is the exact error with the store. if you are unable to figure it out then just update the question with contain of 1341617007993 file. Without contain of this file it will be difficult to trace a issue.

Comment: Post your error in the mentioned error log as we don't have access to your server :)

Comment: Sorry. I have added details of 1341617007993 log to the original message

Comment: maybe a stupid question but have you tried logging in to admin using a device you havent used before?

Comment: Yes, tried a different device and still no joy

Comment: What About empty Your session folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a combination of a Magento bug when loading singletons and a Model Class that cannot be found.

For some Reason, the Model `mgt_base/feed` is loaded as singleton (`Mage::getSingleton('mgt_base/feed')`) and returns false, since the model cannot be found (`Mage::register('_singleton/mgt_...', false)`)

Since the registry value is false, Magento thinks, it has not been loaded yet, tries to load it again and then write it to the registry with the key that already exists. (because of this code: https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/Mage.php#L476) This raises an exception since this key already exists.

You have to find out, why the Model `mgt_base/feed` cannot be loaded. I can only assume the Namespace and Modulename, but it could / should be located somewhere like this:

```
app/code/local/Mgt/Base/Model/Feed.php

app/code/community/Mgt/Base/Model/Feed.php
```

while the Mgt and Base in the paths are only assumptions.